# Swift Serpent generate JSON with top-level array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm using Serpent (https://github.com/nodes-ios/Serpent) to generate JSON with Swift 3. My object model looks basically like this:

```
import Foundation
import Serpent

struct FooModel
{
    var features = [FooFeature]()
}
extension FooModel: Serializable
{
    init(dictionary:NSDictionary?)
    {
        features <== (self, dictionary, "features")
    }

    func encodableRepresentation() -> NSCoding
    {
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        (dict, "features") <== features
        return dict
    }
}

struct FooFeature
{
    var uri = ""
    var id = ""
    var keyword = ""
    var name = ""
    var tags = [FooTag]()
}
extension FooFeature: Serializable
{
    init(dictionary:NSDictionary?)
    {
        uri <== (self, dictionary, "uri")
        id <== (self, dictionary, "id")
        keyword <== (self, dictionary, "keyword")
        name <== (self, dictionary, "name")
        tags <== (self, dictionary, "tags")
    }

    func encodableRepresentation() -> NSCoding
    {
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        (dict, "uri") <== uri
        (dict, "id") <== id
        (dict, "keyword") <== keyword
        (dict, "name") <== name
        (dict, "tags") <== tags
        return dict
    }
}

struct FooTag
{
    var name = ""
    var line = 0
}
extension FooTag: Serializable
{
    init(dictionary:NSDictionary?)
    {
        name <== (self, dictionary, "name")
        line <== (self, dictionary, "line")
    }

    func encodableRepresentation() -> NSCoding
    {
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        (dict, "name") <== name
        (dict, "line") <== line
        return dict
    }
}
```

... and so on. However the tool I'm writing the JSON output for requires an array to be the top-level. In this case that would be the `features` array.

I would normally do this to get the JSON dictionary:

```
let jsonData = fooModel.encodableRepresentation()
```

but since I need the array to be top-level I should use that one:

```
let jsonData = fooModel.features
JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonData)
```

this results in invalid JSON data. How can I use Serpent to generate the desired JSON format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Serpent` framework adds an extension to `Sequence` that allows you to call `encodableRepresentation()` on arrays where the elements are `Encodable`.

`fooModel.feature.encodableRepresentation()` should give you what you need.

Comment: WUT! You are right, thanks! The code auto-completion in AppCode didn't show anything so I thought this wouldn't work but it compiles after all.